# How do I get the WebBrowser in Windows Phone to navigate to a particular section of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

The web browser in Windows Phone 7.5 does not appear to recognise name or id anchors in a webpage, so for example navigating to `glossary.html#myterm` navigates to the top of the glossary.html page but does not jump down to the `myterm` tag irrespective of whether I specify it as an id or a name. Within a page using `#myterm` works.

I tried to use javascript to get around this i.e. something like,

```
if (document.loaded) {
    init();
} else {
    if (window.addEventListener) {  
        window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent('onload', init);
    }
}

function init() {
    var els = document.URL.split("#");
    if (els.length == 1) {
        return;
    }
    var newurl = '#' + els[els.length - 1];
    window.location.replace(newurl);
}
```

Which also does not work. Bizarrely though, if I attach `init()` to a click event on another element, it *does* work.

Has anyone else solved this?

Comment: Is this a documented bug? I couldn't find any references

Comment: I just suspect it is, since WP is quite immature yet (so to say without using offensive expressions).

Comment: Tried switching id for name, name works even worse than id (i.e. even the click event fired navigation doesn't work)

Comment: This is a known bug which is fixed in WP8. There is a 'possible workaround' according to this forum post (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/4ef168fa-47a7-41a7-9b2d-bdbca774b4bb) which calls `window.location.replace()` from C# but I couldn't get it to work when firing from the OnNavigated event ...